# How can we count number of records and show in rest api?

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter

controller:

```
<?php
    require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
    use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
    class User extends REST_Controller 
    {   
        function country_get()
        {
            $this->db->select('id,name');
            $this->db->from('countries');
            $sql = $this->db->get();
            $result = $sql->result_array();
            $this->response($result, 200);
        }
    }
```

unexpected output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Albania"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Algeria"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "American Samoa"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Andorra"
    }
]
```

expected output:

```
{
"Message": "Number of Country found: 5",
"Status": "Success",
"Country": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Albania"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Algeria"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "American Samoa"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Andorra"
    }
]
```

}

In this code I want to show number of records as I mention in my expected output. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: just use `count()` or you can use count of mysql also.

Comment: use count function count($result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is already an array so use the PHP function [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to get the length of the array:

```
function country_get()
{
   $this->db->select('id,name');
   $this->db->from('countries');
   $sql = $this->db->get();
   $result = $sql->result_array();

   $response = [
       "Message" => "Number of Country found: " . count($result),
       "Status" => "Success",
       "Country" => $result
   ];

   $this->response($response, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, No need to use `count()` CI already giving you a count in `num_rows()`

```
function country_get()
{
     $this->db->select('id,name');
     $this->db->from('countries');
     $sql = $this->db->get();
     $count = $sql->num_rows();
     $result = array();
     $result['Message'] = "Number of Country found: " . $count;
     $result['Status'] = "Success";      
     $result['Country'] = $sql->result_array();
     $this->response($result, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your function with the following code:

```
function country_get()
   {
         $this->db->select('id,name');
         $this->db->from('countries');
         $sql = $this->db->get();
         $res = $sql->result_array();
         $result['Status'] = "Success";
         $result['Message'] = "Total country found ".count($res);
         $result['Country'] = $res
         $this->response($result, 200);
    }
```